# This clock is wrong 

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

My clock is broken, and I can't tell what time it is. Can you help me?

[image: Screenshot of the puzzle clock.]

##### Hints

> For a *length* of time, my clock worked with no issues. All of a sudden the *hands were not* moving and I can no longer tell what time it is.
>  There are commonalities between the lengths of the line segments.
>  I *think* the combination of the hour and minute hands is creating new segments, but I can't be sure.

Comment: I'm gonna assume the obvious guess is wrong?

Comment: @Ankit depends on what your *obvious* guess is :)

Comment: rot13(V nz tbvat gb thrff vg vf gjryir abba. vg vf n gjragl sbhe ubhe pybpx naq gur yvar ba gur evtug fvqr bs gur fdhner qrabgrf gur fvqr gung vf zbeavat. Gur "oebxra" cneg vf gung lbhe ahzoref srry bss.) am I on the right path?

Comment: @rhavelka no, sorry.

Comment: well, twice a day it should be right :D

Comment: rot13(Ner gur yvarf ryrpgevp pvephvg flzobyf?)

Comment: @Pureferret no, sorry.

Comment: @Tacoタコス rot13(Vf guvf chmmyr eryngrq gb gur pbybe oyhr naq O?

Comment: @Prim3numbah not sure how it would be.

Comment: Ok, wrong track then

Comment: @Tacoタコス Another hint maybe?

Comment: @Prim3numbah your wish is my command.

Comment: if it helps anyone, here are the approximate measurements: rot13(va crepragntrf (naq cvkryf): bar uhaqerq (gjbsvirmreb) sbe gur ybat unaq, friragl svir (barrvtugfrira.svir) sbe gur fubeg unaq, svsgrra (guerrfrira.svir) sbe gur ovt fdhner, frira.svir sbe gur fznyy fdhner, bar uhaqerq naq svsgrra (gjbrvtugfrira.svir) sbe gur enqvhf bs gur pvepyr)

Comment: @somebody, that’s a *bit* too far.

Comment: It's always given me the impression that it's rot13(fvqrjnlf jvgu gur rqtr snpvat lbh) but not quite sure how that would help.

Answer (score 9):

I believe what you need to do is

> Bring your clock outside on a sunny day

Because

> It looks like it is a sundial as seen from above with the vertical line through the centre representing the gnomon. It probably stopped working when you no longer had access to the sun.

Comment: rot13(Be vg vf abba naq gur funqbj qvfnccrnerq)

Answer (score 5):

For lack of a better idea...

[image]

It was 16:27:57, but I am not sure about the time zone.

Comment: Time zone would be UTC, since that's what SE runs on

Comment: Funny, because right after posting I thought I should've waited to make it match the answer, but alas, maybe next time.

Comment: Now we know you are asking for a specific time of the day, not a way to fix the clock.